# How to us timestamp in query builder in laravel 5.3 to tack users registered in last 5 days

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I want to list down the users who are registered in last 5 day.. To list down all the users 1 use following query..

```
$users = User::select('*')->orderby('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

and fetch it in view like this.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>User Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Points</th>
                            </tr>

                            <?php foreach ( $users as $u ){ ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $u->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->user_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->country }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->created_at }}</td>
                                <td>{{ \App\Points::getUserPoints($u->id) }}</td>
                            </tr>



                            <?php }?>

                            </tbody></table>
```

but what will be the query to fetch users who have registered in last 5 days..?? any one please tell me a good query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) ([docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)) to do this:

```
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $users = User::where('created_at', '>=', $now->subDays(5))->get();
```

Make sure to "`use Carbon\Carbon;`" at the top of the file.